# Log OutputDebugString to a file (without DebugView)

Tags: winapi

My WPF app consumes a third-party Win32 dll that logs messages via OutputDebugString.

I can see the OutputDebugString messages in Visual Studio or via DebugView, but I don't want to ask my customer to run DebugView. I'd like to capture the messages from OutputDebugString and automatically log them to a file, so if the customer has a problem, I can just ask her to send me that log file.

Is this possible? Or does the user necessarily have to start DebugView, reproduce the error, and then send me the log that way?

Comment: You can certainly do it, but you'll need to write your own debug listener, and then you've basically written an inferior clone of DebugView. The DLL shouldn't really be doing that. OutputDebugString is intended for debugging purposes only, and shouldn't even be called under normal circumstances in release builds. It's meant for someone debugging the code to watch, not a log file.

Comment: I'll file a bug, but the DLL is out of my hands. :-(

Comment: Assuming you do want to actually just clone DebugView, this article is helpful: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23776/Mechanism-of-OutputDebugString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hook `OutputDebugStringW`. I'd suggest using the [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) library for this.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <detours.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")

BOOL SetHook(__in BOOL bState, __inout PVOID* ppPointer, __in PVOID pDetour)
{
  if (DetourTransactionBegin() == NO_ERROR)
    if (DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread()) == NO_ERROR)
      if ((bState ? DetourAttach : DetourDetach)(ppPointer, pDetour) == NO_ERROR)
        if (DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)
          return TRUE;
  return FALSE;
{

#define InstallHook(x, y) SetHook(TRUE, x, y)  

VOID (WINAPI * _OutputDebugStringW)(__in_z_opt LPCWSTR lpcszString) = OutputDebugStringW;

VOID WINAPI OutputDebugStringHook(__in_z_opt LPCWSTR lpcszString)
{
  // do something with the string, like write to file

  _OutputDebugStringW(lpcszString);
}

// somewhere in your code
InstallHook((PVOID*)&_OutputDebugStringW, OutputDebugStringHook);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Cody Gray's suggestion to "write your own debug listener, and then you've basically written an inferior clone of DebugView" sounds like it might actually be an answer to my question.

Here's [a C# implementation of a basic OutputDebugString capture tool](http://www.michaelfcollins3.me/blog/2013/06/01/understanding-outputdebugstring.html). I'd seen it in my Googling a couple of times, but my eyes glazed over it, assuming, "that can't possibly be what I want, can it?" Turns out, it just might be the answer to my question.

Comment: So writing a Debug Listener was in fact the only way to do that? That is crazy. What about automating test application runs?